# Is it possible to parse DateTime from "-3:00:00" string?

Tags: .net, datetime, datetime-parsing

I have a string representing time offset.

Can I build a DateTime object from that?

I mean if the the negative value is OK?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to parse a `TimeSpan` not a `DateTime`

Comment: I have not. I have a third party library that has an method taking DateTime as parameter. I am facing the fact that I need to feed it with -3:00:00” value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TimeSpan s;
if (!TimeSpan.TryParse("-3:00:00", out s))
    throw new ArgumentException();
```

then

```
DateTimeOffset offset = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Not, s); // -3
DateTime d = offset.DateTime; // or .Date
```

Comment: Kinda useless to use `TryParse` if you throw an exception if the parsing is not successful. This mimics the behavior of `Parse`, so why not use it?

Comment: @Daniel: That's just an example how to react on unsuccessful parsing attempt

Comment: @Daniel: Also `Parse()` throws 3 different exceptions, and you can throw a custom one (without catching and re-throwing)

Comment: All right, so kinda hack to cheat DateTime and not use TryParse

Comment: @Captain: if you need only time part, don't hack DateTime, just use TimeSpan which is actually created for such purpose

Answer (score 4):

If it's an offset, shouldn't you use `TimeSpan` rather than `DateTime`? This should also handle negative time spans.

Answer (score 1):

[this website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) shows all the information about parsing date time strings